# Disable validation when previous button is pressed

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

I have a multistep webform with required fields. The problem is that when I press the "previous"button in order to go to the page before the validation triggers and does not allow me to change the page. How can I disable the validation if the "previous" button is pressed?

I followed [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/243614/webform-multistep-form-previous-button-asks-to-fill-the-required-fields) but it didnt work by adding this code:

```
if(isset($form['actions']['wizard_prev'])){
  $form['actions']['wizard_prev']['#validate'] = ['::noValidate'];
}
```

Comment: Where did you write that code?

Comment: @Jdrupal in hook_form_alter. I also use the https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation module

Comment: You could try `$form['actions']['wizard_prev']['#limit_validation_errors'] = [];` instead.

Comment: If the validation is set with JS, you can't remove it by PHP.